# Create Animated UIView from top to bottom with corner radius

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I developed an iOS app, and I have an animation in it, I would like to create an [animation like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3gH2.gif).

I tried:

```
blueView.backgroundColor = .blue
let duration = 1
let radius = blueView.frame.height / 2

self.blueView.frame.size = CGSize(width:   50, height:   50)
blueView.layer.cornerRadius = radius
if #available(iOS 11, *) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), animations: {
       self.blueView.frame.size = CGSize(width:   self.view.frame.width, height:   self.view.frame.height)    
    }, completion: { _ in
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), animations: {

                            self.blueView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
                        })
    })
}
```

But I didn't achieve what I want, any idea or help to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're missing updating the blueView radius in your animation as a start.
Below are some quick changes/additions to get close to the animation that you mentioned. 
I added the view programmatically, and made minimal changes to your code.

```
let blueView: UIView = {
    // set starting position of view here
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width , y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    view.backgroundColor = .blue
    view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.height / 2
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(blueView)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let duration: TimeInterval = 1

    if #available(iOS 11, *) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
            // set blue view size to double the screen so it can cover full screen with corner radius
            self.blueView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.height * 2, height:   self.view.frame.height * 2)
            // update corder radius to equal new size
            self.blueView.layer.cornerRadius = self.view.frame.height
            // Set ending position of view here to offset new size and radius
            self.blueView.center = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, y: 0)
        }, completion: { _ in
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {
                self.blueView.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height:   self.view.frame.height)
                self.blueView.layer.cornerRadius = 0
                self.blueView.center = self.view.center
            })
        })
    }
}
```

I'm sure this can be done a different way, but I wanted to keep code close to what you started with in hopes that it helps you understand what I changed.

Comment: Many thanks valosip, I so appreciate your effort,  but How can animation start from right to left as in image which I provided before?

Comment: Take a look at the above code and play around with the values.   As it is written now, there are only 2 spots where you need to change in order to move the location of the view.   The starting and ending.   Try to make your own edits instead of asking others to do everything for you in the future.  @AliAlaoi . I'll update the answer with detail this one time